# Soma entre DIVs e exibir resultado em outra div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Não entendo o pq não consigo executar o seguinte script pois sou um tanto quanto leigo:

```
    <div class="prices"> 
<h3>Option 1 = $<span class="sum" id="option-1">11.11</span></h3>
<h3>Option 2 = $<span class="sum" id="option-2">22.22</span></h3>
</div>
<div id="subtotal"></div>
```

e o script...

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $('#option-1, #option-2').blur(function(){
        var sum = $('#option-1').text();
        var sum2 = $('#option-2').text();

        if(sum == "") sum = 0;
        if(sum2 == "") sum2 = 0;

        var resultado   = parseInt(sum) + parseInt(sum2);
  $("#subtotal").text(resultado);
    })

});
```

Ou se teria algum meio mais simples de fazer essa função porém preciso que seja especificado cada div.

Comment: Aparece algum erro no console?

Comment: Nenhum erro :((

Comment: Esses valores podem ser mudados dinamicamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**O resultado desejado <sub>(quando você clica em qualquer lugar)</sub> pode ser obtido com**

`$(document).click(function() {`

**pois com**

`$('#option-1, #option-2').blur(function(){`

dito por **Vinicius.Beloni** 
<sub>"o .blur é uma função que se espera a perca de foco, tags como span não tem foco"</sub>

```js
$(document).ready( function() {

    $(document).click(function() {
    
        var sum = $('#option-1').text();
        var sum2 = $('#option-2').text();

        if(sum == "") sum = 0;
        if(sum2 == "") sum2 = 0;

        var resultado   = parseInt(sum) + parseInt(sum2);

        $("#subtotal").text(resultado);

    })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="prices"> 
<h3>Option 1 = $<span class="sum1" id="option-1">11.11</span></h3>
<h3>Option 2 = $<span class="sum2" id="option-2">22.22</span></h3>
</div>
<div id="subtotal"></div>
```

Comment: isso ai, com o  `.click` resolve muito bem a questão do colega, obrigado pela citação :D

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente e aprimorei com attr. para facilitar... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

pois muito bem, o .blur é uma função que se espera a perca de foco, tags como `span` não tem foco, basta fazer um `.hover` ao invés do `.blur` que vc vê perfeitamente que funciona seu código. vou postar aqui a prova do que eu to falando, basta tirar o foco de algum input que teu resultado aparece.

```
 <div class="prices"> 
    <h3>Option 1 = $<input type='text' class="sum" id="option-1"n value='11.11'/></h3>
    <h3>Option 2 = $<input type='text' class="sum" id="option-2" value='22.22' /></h3>
</div>
<div id="subtotal"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {
    $('#option-1, #option-2').blur(function(){
        var sum = $('#option-1').val();
        var sum2 = $('#option-2').val();

        if(sum == "") sum = 0;
        if(sum2 == "") sum2 = 0;

        var resultado   = parseInt(sum) + parseInt(sum2);
        $("#subtotal").text(resultado);
    })

})();
</script>
```